# Showing part of one sheet on a second sheet (keeping conditional formatting)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet called [Calendar] with a calendar for each month of the year, this sheet has conditional formatting to colour each date depending on holidays/capacity for that month. These dates are also set in the [Calendar] sheet.

I have a second sheet for each month (eg. [Jan 2022], this sheet has lots of information about what's happening that month.

I'd like to have that months calendar from [Calendar] show up on [Jan 2022] keeping all of the conditional formatting. Is this possible?

(I realise that I could re-do all of the conditional formatting on the Monthly sheets based on the info in [Calendar] using `Calendar!Range` in the conditions but there are 45 different sets of conditional formatting as well as a script which changes the border colour of certain cells if they match other conditions on the sheet. I was wondering if there was an easier way)

Comment: You can copy format from source sheet to destination. `sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true})`. Almost in the same way you can copy background colors. But I'm not sure about borders. Borders is whole another thing. They can be copied via Sheet API, but it's a much more complicated matter.

Comment: The problem is, I'd just like to copy 1 month (eg. just Jan 2022) from the [Calendar] and that would make up just one part of the [Jan 2022] sheet, the rest would be to-do lists, upcoming events etc. etc. I'd really like to just 'show' a certain range from another sheet [Calendar!E7:K14] as it is on the other sheet, is there no way of embedding part of another sheet?

Comment: To 'embedding' a part of another sheet you can use standard 'IMPORTRAGE()' function. But it 'copies' (don't copies actually, just shows) data without formatting. It means to reuse a formatting of the destination sheet (destination range, a part of the destination sheet). So if you have more or less constant formatting (colors, font styles) you can use IMPORTRANGE. But if you want to change formatting in source or in destination, it can demand some scripts of manually corrections every time you change the formatting.

Comment: When you say you just want it to `show` a certain range, do you mean any changes in the original range should be updated in the destination range? If that's the case, you could use a combination of an `onEdit` trigger and `copyTo`. This way, every time a change is made to the source range, the range data (including conditional formatting and borders) would be copied to the destination range. This would only work for user edits though. Can you please clarify if that would be a desired behavior? In that case, I'd consider posting an answer.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'd need. Although, the [Calendar] sheet (showing all the monthly calendars for the next couple of years) would probably only be updated once a month or so but the page for that month [Jan 2022] would be updated daily. I probably wouldn't need to 'refresh' that months calendar on every edit made on [Jan 2022] but would like it to refresh each time an edit is made on [Calendar] if that's possible. I'll try to make an example sheet and link it above.

Comment: Ok, example sheet created @lamblichus

Comment: I see. The problem here is that the values and the conditional formatting depend on formulas which reference current sheet. When these are copied to the new sheet, they break, since the destination sheet doesn't have the desired information in the corresponding cell references. Probably the best way around this would be to modify the formulas and conditional formatting to reference sheet `Calendar`, and not just current sheet. Would that be feasible for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After a LOT of messing about, I've found a few possible solutions that worked.

Firstly, you can copy/paste the area you'd like to 'show' which will also copy the formatting over, sadly this formatting doesn't link to the correct page anymore (if, as in my case, you're not also copying the information that the conditions rely on).

The easiest way I found was to copy the fields that the conditions rely on into the same fields on the sheet you're copying to (eg. in the cell Jan!X10 put the code `=Calendar!X10` and do the same for X10:Z20 for example). This means that when [Calendar] is updated, the conditional formatting on [Jan] changes to represent this.
[one last tip, after putting the code in the matching cells, you can then either hide these cells OR copy/paste these cells to somewhere that works better in your sheet and the references in the conditional formatting will update]

The other way I found to do it is to change the [Jan] conditional formatting to reference the [Calendar] page, sadly, you cant simply change `=A1>X10` to `=A1>Calendar!X10`, you need to change it to `=A1>INDIRECT("'Calendar'!X10")` as you cant directly use a cross-sheet reference in Conditional Formatting (for some reason).

I hope this helps anyone who is having the same problems I was having. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

There is current a feature request to set a ranges border color and style.  If you want that sort of feature you may wish to go to this issue and star the request.

[36756953](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756953)

Comment: Border color and style can be set, see [setBorder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal,-color,-style). This FR was marked as fixed some time ago https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756953#comment27.

Comment: It's still annoying how you cant set a border color with Conditional Formatting tho.